# changing uppercase file names in AWS S3 to lowercase

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, amazon-s3

I'd like to ask for help with changing uppercase file names in AWS S3 to lowercase.

I got two files, one's a list of file names from an AWS S3 bucket with upper case letter like so (lets call it uppercase.txt):

```
ABc.txT

aBCd.pHp

AbCdE.jpg
```

and a second file with a list of the translation of the names to lower case (lowercase.txt, easily done with tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'):

```
abc.txt

abcd.php

abcde.jpg
```

I tried a bunch of for loops, the command I wish to repeat is 'aws s3 mv $first_list_value $second_list_value .

Tried this:

```
for i in `cat uppercase_file.txt`; do aws s3 mv $i `cat lowercase_file.txt`; done
```

no dice :-( The AWS S3 API is limited and doesn't take well to most linux commands.

Yelp?

Comment: That wouldn't work on anything. You are attempting to move the uppercase file + all lowercase filenames to the last filename in `lowercase_file.txt` as though it were a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
paste uppercase_file.txt lowercase_file.txt | while read uc lc
do
  aws s3 mv $uc $lc
done
```